# MYSQL Trigger UPDATE after UPDATE

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to define a trigger in my table. I have columns GRP_UX and GRP_UID, one being the interface style and the other the group of people it is assigned to. For whatever reason (or whomever) from time to time, the GRP_UX is set to a different value than it should be.

I want to create a trigger that when GRP_UX is updated from let's say value Y to X where GRP_UID = sales_guys, that the value is put back to Y. I have tried many solutions or tried to patch together many scripts, but they all error out.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: You`d be better to find out the source of the anomaly rather than creating solutions for vague situations.Besides you cant update in an AFTER UPDATE trigger

Comment: You would have to use a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger